# how to auto select value in dropdown in jsp using javascript for view filled data

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I made one form in html, if user submit form then value stored in form will stored in database.
and i put one option **Edit** if user click on edit then open that filled form in model, but how to fill the dropdown in html.

this is my form code

```
<!-- Large Modal -->
<div id="additem" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content ">
            <div class="modal-header pd-x-20">
                <h6 class="modal-title">Message Preview</h6>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="additem" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-body pd-20">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Item Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="hidden" value="${shopkeeper.sk_id}" name="sk_id">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter item name here..." name="name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Item Type</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select class="btn btn-primary m-b-5 m-t-5" name="itemtype">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Item Type</option>
                                <option value="Grocery">Grocery</option>
                                <option value="Bread and Dairy">Bread and Dairy</option>
                                <option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
                                <option value="Beverages">Beverages</option>
                                <option value="Sweets">Sweets</option>
                                <option value="Packed Snack">Packed Snack</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Item Brand</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter item brand here..." name="brand">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Item Price</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter item price here..." name="price">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Price with
                            Discount</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter item price here..." name="offerprice">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Item Image</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="form-group files color  mb-lg-0">
                                <input type="file" class="file" class="form-control1"
                                    name="image" accept="image/*">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Product
                            Availability</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select class="btn btn-primary m-b-5 m-t-5" name="availability">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Product
                                    Availability</option>
                                <option value="In Stock">In Stock</option>
                                <option value="Out of Stock">Out of Stock</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Item Description</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"
                                placeholder="Enter item description here..." name="description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-right m-b-5 m-t-20" id="Button">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <!-- modal-body -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Item</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- modal -->
```

this is my button code for load data when click on edit this code will execute

```
<button class="adtocart"
                                                        onclick="loaddata(${listitem.item_id},'${listitem.name}','${listitem.brand}','${listitem.price}','${listitem.description}','${listitem.availability}','${listitem.itemtype}',${listitem.offerprice});"
                                                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edititem">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                                    </button>
```

this is my javascript function for handel data send by button. this how i fill the value of text box

```
function loaddata(item_id,name,brand,price,description,availability,itemtype,offerprice)
   {
       alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
       document.f1.item_id.value=item_id;
       document.f1.name.value=name;
       document.f1.brand.value=brand;
       document.f1.price.value=price;
       document.f1.description.value=description;

   }
```

below code is for display filled form for edit data

```
<!-- Edit Item Model Start -->
<!-- Large Modal -->
<div id="edititem" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content ">
            <div class="modal-header pd-x-20">
                <h6 class="modal-title">Edit Item</h6>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="edititem" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                name="f1">
                <div class="modal-body pd-20">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Item Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="hidden" value="${shopkeeper.sk_id}" name="sk_id">
                            <input type="hidden" id="item_id" name="item_id"> <input
                                type="text" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter item name here..." name="name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Item Type</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select class="btn btn-primary m-b-5 m-t-5" name="itemtype">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Item Type</option>
                                <option value="Grocery">Grocery</option>
                                <option value="Bread and Dairy">Bread and Dairy</option>
                                <option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
                                <option value="Beverages">Beverages</option>
                                <option value="Sweets">Sweets</option>
                                <option value="Packed Snack">Packed Snack</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Item Brand</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter item brand here..." name="brand">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Item Price</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter item price here..." name="price">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Item Image</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="form-group files color  mb-lg-0">
                                <input type="file" class="file" class="form-control1"
                                    name="image" accept="image/*">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Item Description</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"
                                placeholder="Enter item description here..." name="description"
                                id="description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-right m-b-5 m-t-20" id="Button">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <!-- modal-body -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Item</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- modal -->
<!-- Edit Item Model End -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I don't really know what you are looking for. But maybe this piece of code would be helpful.

```js
function selectOption(value) 
{
  // get the select
  const selectTest = document.f1.itemtype;
  
  // the loop runs over all options
  for (let i = 0; i < selectTest.options.length; i++) 
  {
    
   if( value === selectTest.options[i].value)
    {
     // if the "value" is an possible option 
      // this option is selected and the loop is aborted.
      
     selectTest.options[i].selected = true;
      break;
    }  
      
  }

}

// call the function with the value of the second option
selectOption('test2');
```

```html
<form name="f1">
  <select name="itemtype" >
    <option value="test1">TEST 1</option>
    <option value="test2">TEST 2</option>
    <option value="test3">TEST 3</option>
    <option value="test4">TEST 4</option>
    <option value="test5">TEST 5</option>
    <option value="test6">TEST 6</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Great sir, i get solution exactly what i looking for ,it's 100% working thank you

Comment: sir, i want to also do this thing with image. is it possiable??

Comment: You could transfer the picture name or the picture path into the editing dialog. And in the dialog you could then hide the upload button and display the image using an img tag.